# How to make a cake sweeter without adding too much sugar into it?

Tags: cake

How can make our cake much sweeter without adding too much sugar into it or what can we add in our cake instead of using too much sugar that make our cake sweet.

Comment: what kind of cake is it? Sweet spices like cinnamon, nutmeg, cardamom, can increase the perceived sweetness of a cake, but they will also influence the final taste. Adding fruits or sweet vegetables, like@johanna suggested, can increase the sweetness of a cake too, but I guess your cake will be quite different from the original...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don’t want to change the cake itself (because it needs experience and just using less or more sugar can ruin the cake texture), you can always add a small amount of something very sweet to the baked cake, either when finishing it or when serving.

For example, consider

- a sugary glaze
- a syrupy drizzle
- a sweet filling

Match the flavor to your cake, for example picking

- sugar icing
- a fruity jam or lemon curd
- caramel
- a (Swiss) meringue topping
- ...

The trick is to make sure that the sweet addition hits your palate *first*, which means you will perceive an intense sweetness without really using a lot of sugar. You can even combine this with using a low-sugar (= not very sweet) cake recipe as the base.